# While Connecting external Active Directory through wso2 identity server below error are showing

Tags: wso2

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} - Cannot create connection to LDAP server. Connection URL: ldap://xx.xxx.xx.x:xxx Error message: Error occurred while obtaining LDAP connection, LDAP connection circuit breaker state set to: open
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserStoreDeploymentManager} - Realm configuration of tenant:-1234  modified with D:\wso2_identity_server\wso2is-5.10.0\wso2is-5.10.0\bin..\repository\deployment\server\userstores\testing.xml
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserStoreDeploymentManager} - User store: contata.in of tenant:-1234 is removed from realm chain.
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - User store: testing of tenant:-1234 is removed from user store chain.
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Cannot create org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.createSecondaryUserStoreManager(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8726)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addSecondaryUserStoreManager(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8798)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$2.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:194)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:191)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addSecondaryUserStoreManager(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8784)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserStoreDeploymentManager.deploy(UserStoreDeploymentManager.java:71)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer.deploy(UserStoreConfigurationDeployer.java:169)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext.(LDAPConnectionContext.java:122)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:227)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:120)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.(ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.java:115)
... 33 more

Comment: What is the version Of IS you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a connectivity problem. Maybe the ldap server is not visible, or port is incorrect. Check it with telnet. If you could detail a little bit more the error and the is version you are using.